# How to find out if a mouse-down event occurred on the scroll-bar or anywhere else in the element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML div which as use as a canvas that contains many objects.

In this canvas, the user can draw a rectangle with the mouse to select the objects. There is a flaw in my implementation: if the canvas is too large and scroll-bar appear, dragging the scrollbars also draws a selection rectangle.

What would be a good approach to discriminate mouse down on the scroll-bar, and mouse-down anywhere else on the component ?

**Edit: I'm not asking how to remove the scrollbars. I want them when they are needed**

**Edit: Here is a minimal fiddle to reproduce the issue I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/jUe8T/**

Comment: code? you can proably solve this with css

Comment: As @Ties said above, you can probably solve this just by setting `overflow: hidden;` on the canvas element. That way no scrollbars appear. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow

Comment: @Chase But I want the scrollbar to appear when they are needed. I'll update the question to make this more clear

Comment: @Ties I'm not trying to remove the scrollbar. I don't see how css could help me know if the user clicked on the scrollbar. Code would be irrelevant here. I'm just looking for an idea to build my solution upon it.

Comment: Is there any way you can include the code so that we can see more in depth?

Comment: i know but you'd be surpised how using semantics and css smartly can solve you're problem without creating complicated js. it's just hard to help you if you don't provide me/us with the right information

Comment: @Ties There's always something to learn. I added a jsfiddle to show the code that produce the issue. I would be happy to find an elegant solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe fiddle was very helpfull as i though you were using the `<canvas>` element... i think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/jUe8T/1/

i did this by adding a `.scroll` event to `$('#canvas')` with `upHandler` as handler, like this:

```
$('#canvas').scroll(upHandler);
```

Comment: Ooops sorry for the misunderstanding. Great and simple solution, thanks.